# Homeomorphism Lifting To Homeomorphism of Lp spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(X,d,x_0)$ be a pointed metric space, $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $X$, and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a homeomorphism satisfying $f(x_0)=0$.  Define the space
$
L^p(\mathbb{R}^D;X),
$
to be the set of measurable functions from $\mathbb{R}^D$ to $X$ satisfying
$$
\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^D}  d(f(x),x_0) d\mu(x)<\infty.
$$
Does the following map define a homeomorphism:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Psi: &L^p(\mathbb{R}^D;X) \mapsto L^p(\mathbb{R}^D;\mathbb{R}^d)\\
g &\mapsto f\circ g
\end{aligned}
$$
where the right-hand side is the [Bochner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space) $L^p$-space?

Comment: I asked a more basic version of this question myself, where the answer is negative, so I have a hard time believing the answer is yes. My version was: can the isomorphism type (in any reasonable sense) of an L^p space detect the topological type of the underlying space? The answer is no for unbounded examples. Consider the interval and the line. They are homeomorphic by some arctangent type construction, with limiting value $\pi/2$, and so the pullback of such maps to the line isn't in any $L^p$ except $p = \infty$ for all but the most trivial functions.

Comment: Could you post a link to the question if its a post on MSE?

Comment: You might want to consider the case when X is the real line, $x_0 =0$, and $f(x)=x^3$.